# MySQL Trigger On A Column

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I hav a table with several fields.  One field is "date_assigned" and the other is "assigned".  "date_assigned" has a datatype of timestamp and can be null.  "assigned" has a datatype of tinyint and the values are either 0 (default; 'not assigned') or 1 ('assigned').

I would like to create a trigger that would automatically update the "assigned" value to 1 when "date_assigned" is updated with a value (is not null).

I've used triggers before, but have not used them in conjunction with checking if a value is null. I'm unclear on the syntax, so any help would be appreciated.  So far, I've tried:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `<database>`.`<trigger_name>` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `<database>`.`<table>`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF(NEW.date_assigned IS NOT NULL) THEN
    UPDATE <table> SET assigned = '1';

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I just get Error Code: 1064.  I looked upo the code, and it appears that it's a syntax error.  So what syntax mistake am I making, and is this even the correct 'grammar'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `BEGIN` in a new line as follows.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `<database>`.`<trigger_name>` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `<database>`.`<table>`
    FOR EACH ROW 

    BEGIN
    IF(NEW.date_assigned IS NOT NULL) THEN
    UPDATE <table> SET assigned = '1';

    END;      //Change here also.
    $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of default delimiter in MySQL set to `;`. So, the first line should look like `DELIMITER $$;`

```
DELIMITER $$;

 CREATE     TRIGGER `<database>`.`<trigger_name>`
 AFTER UPDATE     ON `<database>`.`<table>`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN     
 IF(NEW.date_assigned IS NOT NULL) THEN 
 UPDATE <table> SET assigned = '1';   
 END$$

  DELIMITER ;
```